# Parse error in YAML code with "Fn::Base64" and "Fn::Join" while validating it

Tags: parsing, amazon-web-services, yaml

I have problem in validating the following YAML code, as I'm not able to parse the `Fn::Base64` and `Fn::Join`. How can I resolve this?

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
Description: "test e2 ebs in vpc"
Parameters: 
  KeyPairName: 
    Description: "Public/private key pairs allow you to securely connect to your instance after it launches"
    Type: "AWS::EC2::KeyPair::KeyName"
  VPC: 
    Description: "ID of the VPC (e.g., vpc-0343606e)"
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPC::Id"
  myWSFCNode1InstanceType: 
    ConstraintDescription: "Only EBS Optimized instance types r3.xlarge, r3.2xlarge, r3.4xlarge allowed"
    Default: t2.small
    Description: "Amazon EC2 instance type for the 1st WSFC Node"
    Type: String
Resources: 
  myWSFCNode1: 
    CreationPolicy: 
      ResourceSignal: 
        Count: "1"
        Timeout: PT15M
    Properties: 
      BlockDeviceMappings: 
      -  DeviceName: /dev/sda1
      Ebs: 
          VolumeSize: "100"
          VolumeType: gp2
      ImageId: ami-fd9cecc7
      InstanceType: 
        Ref: myWSFCNode1InstanceType
      KeyName: 
        Ref: KeyPairName
      SecurityGroupIds: 
        - 
          Ref: myWSFCSecurityGroup
      UserData: 
            ? "Fn::Base64"
            : 
            ? "Fn::Join"
            : 
            - ""
            - 
    Type: "AWS::EC2::Instance"
  myWSFCNode1Volume1: 
    Properties: 
      Size: 50
    Type: "AWS::EC2::Volume"
  myWSFCSecurityGroup: 
    Properties: 
      GroupDescription: "Enable the WSFC and SQL AlwaysOn Availability Group communications"
      SecurityGroupIngress: 
        - 
          CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
          FromPort: "22"
          IpProtocol: tcp
          ToPort: "22"
      VpcId: Ref: VPC
    Type: "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup"
  mySystemGroup: "ec2SG"
```

Comment: @LukaKerr If you edit a post, please don't just do the code formatting once you have it opened for editing, clean up the whole post.

Comment: What do you use to validate this YAML. Can you pre-process the file before handing it to the process that currently does the validation?

Answer (score 0):

This part is not valid YAML:

```
UserData:
      ? "Fn::Base64"
      : 
      ? "Fn::Join"
      : 
      - ""
      -
```

`?` and `:` denote explicit mapping keys and values. This makes the value of `UserData` a YAML mapping. Then, there are two sequence items denoted with `-`. There cannot be any sequence items in a YAML mapping, therefore, the parser fails.

Depending on what you want to do, here are some changes that may do what you want:

1. Having the sequence as value inside the mapping:

```
? "Fn::Base64"
: 
? "Fn::Join"
: 
  - ""
  -
```

2. Transform the two sequence items into another key-value pair:

```
? "Fn::Base64"
: 
? "Fn::Join"
: 
? ""
:
```

Note that YAML allows empty values to be left out in some cases, so you can condense 1. into:

```
? "Fn::Base64" 
? "Fn::Join"
: 
  -
  -
```

And 2. into:

```
? "Fn::Base64"
? "Fn::Join"
?
```

Comment: The sequence with two elements (emtpy string and nill) is the value for the key `Fn::Join`, YAML allows non-indented values that are sequences.

Comment: This is a rather blurry topic in the spec. It says that mapping *and* sequence indicators are considered part of the indentation. While you are technically correct in that the grammar productions in the spec only handle sequence indicators and therefore, this could parse, an implementation might also honor the text description which contradicts it. So I would certainly not depend on it.

Comment: I don't agree the spec is blury: "Since people perceive the “-” indicator as indentation, nested block sequences may be indented by one less space to compensate, except, of course, if nested inside another block sequence (block-out context vs. block-in context)." And the spec has multiple examples of such non-indented block sequences that are mapping values.

Comment: Hi Flyx and Anthon... Still I'm unable to resolve this error. Can you please suggest me some more option so that I can try that out.

Comment: @vanithavani: You have to tell use the error you get.

Comment: @Anthon: I was referring to this paragraph: http://www.yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2778026 I agree that this is very weak considered other parts of the spec, but I am nevertheless cautious about using it.

Comment: Hi Flyx, Im getting the following error  

Error : Unable to parse.
Line : 36  ? "Fn::Base64"

Answer (score 0):

Your YAML file has one single error and that is the line:

```
      VpcId: Ref: VPC
```

which probably should be:

```
      VpcId: "Ref: VPC"
```

because you cannot have `:` in a non quoted string, or potentially:

```
      VpcId: 
        Ref: VPC
```

If, after correcting the above, your parser doesn't accept the `Fn::Base64` string, then you should upgrade your parser.

Comment: Hi Anthon , 
Still I'm not able to resolve this error. I'm getting the following error. 


Unable to parse. Line : 36 ? "Fn::Base64"

Comment: @vanithavani  Have you upgraded your parser? Which one are you using to validate your stuff? Can you preprocess the YAML to a format with the same semantics that is accepted by your YAML parser?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys for your time helping me.. I got the fix with the following change in my code.

```
  UserData: 
        ? "Fn::Base64":
        ? "Fn::Join":
        - ""
        -
```